# How to set default Background Color for the custom Elementor widget

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor

I want to set a default background color to custom widget when someone drag the widget to page in Elementor Page Builder.

[image: I have added a custom background gradient color to the widget]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Elementor Pro you can add "Custom CSS" for widgets: https://elementor.com/help/custom-css-pro/.

You can then set these subset of widgets to display the correct background colour or gradient.

Example:

```css
#widget {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black, grey);
  width: 750px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, 
No, I am creating a theme for all type of customers, so I can't use this solution. Is there any way like we set default values for Elementor controls ? `'default' => __( 'Mordernize Your Business', 'text-domain' ),`

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Just create a widget, save it as a template and call where you can add elements.

**Option 2: add css in appearance->customize->Additional CSS**

add class on the widget where you want to add bg color

```
    .your-class{
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black, grey) !important;
 }
```